# Smartface add searchbar to actionbar

Tags: smartface.io

I want to add searchbar in actionbar. I don't know how to do this. Can you show me an example code. Maybe this code may be incorrect.

```
srcBar = new SMF.UI.SearchBar({
    width:"100%",
    height:"10%",
    left:"0%",
    top:"20%",
    icon:"arama_icon.png",
    setShowsCancel : true,
    text:""
});

this.actionBar.menuItems = [srcBar];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. We need to use actionView for android and stickToNavigationBar for iOS.

```js
   var srcBar = new SMF.UI.SearchBar({
    
        width:"100%",
        height:"10%",
        left:"0%",
        top:"20%",
        icon:"arama_icon.png",
        setShowsCancel : true,
        text:"",
        actionView:true,
        stickToNavigationBar:true,
        fontColor:"white"
        
    
    });
    
    
    
    
    Pages.FrmGoruntuleme.add(srcBar);
```